# Move the annotation from one location to another in ios

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview

In my project i need to show my user travelled path from start to end with car moving animation in map. I already show those locations & draw a route line successfully.

> Now i want to animate or move the annotation from start to end.

I tried below code to move the annotation.

```
- (IBAction)btnClick:(id)sender {
    MKPointAnnotation *point=[[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
    [self animateAnnotation:point];
}
-(void) animateAnnotation:(MKPointAnnotation*)annotation{

    CLLocationCoordinate2D newCordinates;
    for(int i=0;i<latArr.count;i++){
        newCordinates=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([latArr[i] doubleValue], [longArr[i] doubleValue]);
        [UIView
         animateWithDuration:2.0
         delay:2.0
         options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
         animations:^{
                         annotation.coordinate = newCordinates;
                     }
                     completion:nil];
    }
}
```

In this i added all locations & drawed the route(greenline)

[image]

This when i click the move annnotaion but i comming from some other locations.

[image]

Comment: You want to use only one annotation every time or anything else ?

Comment: whatever i want to move this car

Comment: car is a annotation or imageView ?

Comment: as of now i put one imageview

Comment: instead of imageview use MKAnnotationView which help you to update coordinates also allow to add any image

Comment: You can following this link to add MKAnnotationView
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26192186/how-to-add-an-image-for-each-customized-annotation-on-mapview

Comment: i tried annotation view it not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40650366/move-the-annotation-on-map-like-uber-ios-application